# Properly handling android resizing of sprite sheets

Tags: android, algorithm, image-processing, sprite-sheet

I have some 1-row sprite sheets for the game I'm working on. I provide them in the `drawable-xhdpi` folder only, and I'm letting the OS do the resizing for me on other densities.

The following problem occurs with this approach:

I have a `1750` width sprite sheet (`xhdpi` width), containing `5` states. So each individual sprite has width `1750 / 5 = 350`. On `hdpi`, this gets resized to `1313`, so each individual sprite has width `1313 / 5 = 262.6`. However, this is actually `262`, since android doesn't let you work with floating point numbers in the `Rect` you have to pass as `source` to `drawBitmap`.

The problem with this is that I cannot properly extract the individual sprites: when drawing them, each successive sprite will shift a little to the right, which I don't want. Is there a way I can fix this? I tried and it works if I manually resize them to `1315` and provide this resized version in `drawable-hdpi`, but this increases APK size a lot and I don't want to do it.

**Note 1:** each individual sprite is surrounded by a lot of transparency on each side (same amount on both sides). I can afford to lose a pixel or two of this transparency, I just cannot have the middle, non-transparent part shift.

**Note 2:** this does not only happen between `xhdpi -> hdpi`. The same issue remains when resizing to the other density classes. The solution has to be general: for any resize coefficient (or at least `6/8`, `4/8` and `3/8`), for any width and for any amount of individual sprites.

To better see the problem, imagine that this is the space where the (automatically resized sprite) needs to be drawn:

```
| _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ |
```

This is how the first frame is drawn (taken from `0 * 262 to 0 + 262` in the sprite sheet, the `*` represents the non-transparent part I care about):

```
| _ _ _ _ * * _ _ _ _ |
```

This is how the second frame is drawn (taken from `1 * 262 to 262 + 262` in the sprite sheet):

```
| _ _ _ _ _ & & _ _ _ |
```

When it should be:

```
| _ _ _ _ & & _ _ _ _ |
```

And so on for each successive frame (at least I THINK for each successive frame. The effect is a lot less noticeable on the actual device, but it is there).

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have this problem even if you manually resize the sprite sheet. The easiest way to this would be to generate your sprite sheet at the correct size for each build (or it it doesn't exist). You'll need each frame of your spritesheet as a separate, correctly centered and largest sized image file possible.

Now, you can use [ImageMagick's CLI](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php). Use a shell script to

1. [Resize](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) each large image to the desired height of the sprite sheet (scale the width to maintain aspect ratio)
2. Use the [Montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/montage.php) command to generate your sprite sheet. Note that cleverly written scripts can even generate rectangular sprite sheets.

Now there shouldn't be any problem. :) Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I'm doing currently but I would like to avoid it, as it almost triples the size of the program.

Comment: Ideally - you'd generate an APK for each screen size, no?

Comment: For each screen size yes (medium screen phones + large and xlarge tablets in my case), but I would like to avoid having to do it for each DPI too (although is that possible? If there's no solution, that wouldn't be too bad). Plus, it's also an interesting problem I think.

Comment: Can you use floating point values as the sprite rectangle on the sprite sheet? If you're using OpenGL (or something similar) to render the sprites then there might be another solution.

Comment: No, the sprite rectangle can only be defined by integers. I am not using OpenGL. For now I have just dropped the sprite sheets and am using a file for each frame.